# cierra vs cerrado?

Tags: verbos

I'm learning Spanish and I'm puzzled by this exam question which I'm supposed to render in Spanish:

```
This store never closes in the afternoon.
```

I would think the translation would be:

```
Esta tienda nunca es cerrada en la tarde
```

But apparently the exam wanted "cierra" instead of "cerrada".   I'm not familiar with "cierra" - is it just an odd conjugation of "cerrar" or a completely separate word?

Comment: In common with many other verbs _cerrar_ changes the stem slightly in various parts of its conjugation. https://www.spanishdict.com/guide/stem-changing-verbs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Esta tienda nunca 'cierra' por la tarde
>
> `This store never 'closes' in the afternoon`

Just as in its English counterpart, here '[cierra](https://dle.rae.es/cerrar?m=form)' is using the conjugation of the verb cerrar (in the third person singular simple present tense that corresponds)

For using the present participle 'cerrada' you may hear

> Esta tienda nunca está 'cerrada' por la tarde
>
> `This store is never 'closed' in the afternoon`

Comment: +1 but I think that "se encuentra" is just introducing extra unnecessary information in this case, making it harder to see the paralelism between OP's sentence and the equivalent Spanish version.

Comment: Thank you very much!  Conjugations of Spanish verbs are more complex than English (it seems so to me anyway.)   Maybe I need to upgrade my Spanish-English dictionary.

Answer (score 2):

I think that @ipp answer is totally correct but I would like to explain more clearly your sentences both in Spanish and in English for clarity.

> [EN] This store never **closes** in the afternoon.
> [ES] Esta tienda nunca **cierra** por la tarde

--

> [EN] This store **is** never closed in the afternoon.
> [ES] Esta tienda nunca **está** cerrada por la tarde

You can translate both sentences almost word for word. There is a slight difference in the idiomatic position of never/nunca. Both pairs of sentences transmit the same meaning but here you can see the reason of your answer not being correct: you introduced a verb that was not present in the original sentence: **es** (to be / ser o estar). Also in that specific case, we use verb "estar" instead of "ser".

Comment: word for word, not by. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
*Esta tienda nunca es cerrada en la tarde*
```

The reason the above answer is not correct, is basically, because your sentence is in past tense (cerrada = past tense of cerrar). And, if you pay attention to the question, the verb is not in past tense.

So, the correct answer is:

```
Esta tienda no cierra por la tarde
```

Honestly, that response is accepted BUT, not is used in real life (at least among native Spanish speakers). What you would see if you travel to latin America is the following:

```
No cerramos por la tarde. 
No cerramos al mediodía. 
Estamos abiertos por la tarde. 
Estamos abiertos al mediodía. 
Estamos abiertos por la noche.
```

Comment: I am a native Spanish speaker and I use that sentence ("Esta tienda no cierra por la tarde") just fine... it is the most common way to say that a shop (not *my* shop) does not close in the afternoon.